# SSRS datetime filed is not refreshed event after the data type in SQL Db was changed from DateTime to Date

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

In my `SSRS 2014 Express report designer` I am displaying a field that had the datatype as `DateTime` in SQL Server and was displaying the data as, for example, `2011-12-31 00:00:00.000`. As a result, the SSRS report was displaying the data as `11/31/2012 12:00:00 AM`. I therefore, changed the datatype in SQL Db from DateTime to Date. Now this column in SQL query designer correctly display the value as 11/31/2012 but in the SSRS report the value is still displayed as 11/31/2012 12:00:00 AM. I've [refreshed the fields in the data set](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dd207055.aspx).

I've checked that the data source is correct. I do know that we can change the date format of the datetime field item in the report designer using for example `=FORMAT(Fields!SellStartDate.Value, "dd/MM/yyyy"`). But I would like to have this change come directly from the data source so we don't have keep using expressions everywhere for the datetime fields. Also, I think it's better performance wise if the data is already formatted in the data source.

Comment: What does your dataset query look like?

Comment: @TTeeple, It's a simple query returning only one record from a single table with no joins or calculated fields etc. Something like `select FirstName, LastName, HiringDate from Employees WHERE EmployeeID = 'Emp123'`

Answer (score 0):

To refresh the field collection in the Report Data Pane for a shared dataset

In the Report Data pane, right-click the dataset, and then click Query.
Click Refresh Fields.

On the report server, the shared dataset query runs and returns the current field collection and any data type changes.  If you change anything on the DB that can effect your query or dataset, you must refresh the metadata.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you are viewing your report in the report builder - it might be cached. Therefore any changes to the Database side doesn't reflect on the report.

To resolve this close your report builder and find the directory where your RDL is stored and delete the .dat file which gets created along with it. Restart report builder and reload the report. It should work.

Good luck 1